# use double integral to find area between difference of two circles

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

> Use a double integral to find the area of the region.
>
> The region inside the circle $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$ and outside the circle $x^2+y^2=1$.

I'm pretty sure my inner integral is going to be $\int_1^{2\cos \theta} r\,dr$  but I'm not sure what to put for my outer integral when integrating with respect to $\theta$. I can see in my notes theres a line tangent to the circle I'm integrating but I'm not sure how to get the exact $\pi$ value that touches it, I can only guess, but my drawing is bad so its hard to guess. The book doesn't really say with this type of problem. I think I also remember my teacher saying I could subtract two equations to get the inner integral but I'm not sure. So how to I set the boundaries and solve?

Comment: Typing out your question is better than attaching figure and use mathjax. Most people would not be able to understand that you are using $S$ to represent integration. use underscore for subscript and caret for superscript.

Comment: btw, click on the "edited" and see how mathjax is done. try it next time.

Comment: oh wow. I didn't know it was as simple as putting dollar signs before and after, I will try to do that from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

Find the intersection point between the two curve.

$$x^2+y^2=1$$
$$(x-1)^2+y^2=1$$

After you find the intersection, $(x,y)$, you can use $\cos^{-1}(x)$ to obtain the corresponding angle.

Edit:

Expanding the second equation $$x^2+y^2-2x+1=1,$$

substitute the first equation into the second equation and solve for $x$.

Comment: can you briefly review how to find their intersection for me?

Comment: i mean find intersection point, solve simultaneous equation?

Comment: I think I've forgotten how to do that

Comment: I edited my post a little bit, solve for $x$.

Comment: thank you. just to be 100% sure, when I solve for x, can i get y by plugging x into any of those equations above? or just certain ones.

Comment: The pair $(x,y)$ have to satisfy all equations. Substitute any of them to get candidates and verify that they indeed satisfy all equations.